# Does SpriteKit or SceneKit support multiplayer?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, multiplayer, scenekit

I want to make a multiplayer game with spriteKit or sceneKit with swift
is this possible? if not when will it be and if it is can you give me a good tutorial on it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, both don't support multiplayer in any way. Let that sink in for a moment ... followed by the realization that, hey, rendering and networking are actually separate frameworks!

Comment: Ok but does that mean i can or cant make a multiplayer game

Comment: @LucasFarleigh,  LearnCocos2D was basically saying the same thing as in the answer by Christian Woerz: That the framework you use for rendering has nothing to do with what you use to implement multi-player capability.

Comment: Yeah, so basically if you have a set of tires and a steering wheel, then yes, you can combine the two to create a car. But enough of the analogies ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

But multiplayer doesn't depend on a framework like SpriteKit or SceneKit. You can implement multi-user capabilities in games like you would do it for other things like a chat or something like that.

Simple multi-user frameworks, that apple provides are either the [`MultipeerConnectivity`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html) framework for local multiplayer or, especially for games, `GameKit` for multiplayer-games over the internet.

There are many tutorials. For GameKit you can check the tutorial on [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1). For the MultipeerConnectivity-Framework I'd recommend you to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html).

Comment: nice for somebody to answer the guy's question.